# InterRail checking the days

Tags: interrail

I want to buy an interrail for Finland and I want to know if I can use all trains there (cuz as I know there not high speed trains !?) ?
and how they check the days you use the ticket ? I mean if I buy 3 days/month how they know which days I use it ?

Answer (score 3):

**Can I use my Interrail pass on all Finnish trains?**

It's worth checking in advance which trains have a surcharge or require reservations. There are certainly high-speed and night trains in Finland.

> Most high-speed and night trains require a reservation at an additional cost.

Source: http://www.interrail.eu/interrail-passes/one-country-pass/finland

**How can transit officials see where I've used my ticket?**

There's a written record: on days you wish to use the pass, you make a written note on it; only then does it become a valid substitute for a normal ticket.

> Fill in your personal details and ticket details before you make your first train journey. For every train, bus or ferry you travel on, you must fill in the journey details before boarding. Make sure to fill in your journey details before boarding the train! Read the full conditions of use of your Interrail pass.

Source: http://www.interrail.eu/passes/how-use-your-interrail-pass

Comment: Even if the Finnish railways label some of their trains as 'high speed trains', they are with average speeds rarely above 100km/h not quite what usually is considered as 'high speed trains'.

Comment: When writing the day, you must always use two digits, i.e. *03* for the third, otherwise you might alter it to *13* ten days later and use it again.

Comment: @gerrit Also, if from the USA, remember the European date order has month in the middle.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The last time I used Interrail, the date order was explicitly indicated on the form (i.e. there were separate fields for day, month, year).